# All Entries on Table 1 but only matching entires on table 2 where table 2 contains where statement

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have a problem joining the following tables in that Table 1 conatins all specialists ie

*John (id1)

Pete (id2)

Harry (id3)

Joanne (id4)*
etc

Table 2 is only populated when a specialist has availability on a certain day ie

*id1  2018-10-19

id3  2018-10-19*

The results I need from the MySQL query when I use the where statement table2.date=2018-10-19 is

*John 2018-10-19

Pete 

Harry 2018-10-19

Joanne*

but what I actually get is

*John 2018-10-19 

Harry 2018-10-19*

which is correct but I need all specialists to show in order.

Can any one help with any suggestions please

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [ask] (especially about homework), hits googling 'stackexhange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text. This is a trivially found faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. hen you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: 'to show in order' -  of what name,id? BTW I suspect you are using an inner join rather than a left join, hard to tell without sight of your query.

Comment: Order by specialis name.  I have tried several queries  including

SELECT * from clinitions LEFT OUTER JOIN availability ON clinitions.cID = availability.aClinition WHERE (availability.aClinition = clinitions.cID OR clinition.cID NOT EXIST) AND availability.aDate ='"&request.querystring("d")&"'

Answer (score 0):

Unless your question is not a good one (and I suspect that it may be a bad one) you don't need the where statement. So

```
drop table if exists t1,t2;

create table t1 (id int,val varchar(10));
insert into t1 values
(1,'John' ),
(2,'Pete' ),
(3,'Harry'),
(4,'Joanne');

create table t2(t1id int,dt date);
insert into t2 values
(1 ,'2018-10-19'),
(3 ,'2018-10-19');

 SELECT * from t1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1id
 order by t1.val;
```

Result

```
+------+--------+------+------------+
| id   | val    | t1id | dt         |
+------+--------+------+------------+
|    3 | Harry  |    3 | 2018-10-19 |
|    4 | Joanne | NULL | NULL       |
|    1 | John   |    1 | 2018-10-19 |
|    2 | Pete   | NULL | NULL       |
+------+--------+------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have no idea how you would get johns,pete,harry,joanne in your result set if you wish to order by name value.
And '"&request.querystring("d")&"'  is not mysql what is this php maybe?

If you are interested in the availability or otherwise for a specific date you would first cross join(creating a cartesian product) specialists to date(s) for example

```
select t1.id,t1.val,dt
 from t1
 cross join (select '2018-10-19' dt 
 #union all select '2018-10-20'
 ) s;
+------+--------+------------+
| id   | val    | dt         |
+------+--------+------------+
|    1 | John   | 2018-10-19 |
|    2 | Pete   | 2018-10-19 |
|    3 | Harry  | 2018-10-19 |
|    4 | Joanne | 2018-10-19 |
+------+--------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and then see if they exist in table2

```
select t.id,t.val,t.dt tdt , ifnull(t2.dt,'Not Available') t2dt
 from 
 (select t1.id,t1.val,dt
 from t1
 cross join (select '2018-10-19' dt 
 #union all select '2018-10-20'
 ) s
 ) t 
 left join t2
 on t.id = t2.t1id and t2.dt = t.dt
 order by t.dt,val;

+------+--------+------------+---------------+
| id   | val    | tdt        | t2dt          |
+------+--------+------------+---------------+
|    3 | Harry  | 2018-10-19 | 2018-10-19    |
|    4 | Joanne | 2018-10-19 | Not Available |
|    1 | John   | 2018-10-19 | 2018-10-19    |
|    2 | Pete   | 2018-10-19 | Not Available |
+------+--------+------------+---------------+
```

Note you can have any number of dates in the cross join by using union. I have 2018-10-20 commented out.

If you have a large range of dates union may become unwieldy and creating a calendar/dates table in your db may be useful and you would substitute that in the cross join. for example

```
select t.id,t.val,t.dt tdt , ifnull(t2.dt,'Not Available') t2dt
 from 
 (select t1.id,t1.val,dt
 from t1
 cross join (select dte dt from dates where dte between '2018-10-19' and '2018-10-19' 
 ) s
 ) t 
 left join t2
 on t.id = t2.t1id and t2.dt = t.dt
 order by t.dt,val;
```

You can of course amend the cross join where condition to whatever you want.

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for going to the trouble of doing this.  Looking back I should have explained this in a little more detail.

The where statement is needed as I only want to get the results from t2 'WHERE the date = xxx' (in this case 2018-10-19) but, as mentioned originally, get all names from t1 even if they do not have an entry in t2 with that date.

If in your example, t2 had several dates, then all of the records would show.

Does that explain better and can you offer more help?

Many Thanks

Comment: @Tim White Edited

Comment: Fantastic.  Many thanks for all your help.  I appreciate you taking the time.